# Which iPad/OS X apps can be used to create music for a game?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, development

Surprisingly many music applications are being available for iOS and (maybe) OS X. Are there ones that can be in fact used for game creation? I'm looking to create in-background music, and maybe special effect sounds.

Comment: Are there any features such a software would need to have which are special to in-game music?

Comment: @patrix: apps that build track from highly predefined samples, I guess they are often called with "DJ" prefix in name.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's very own [GarageBand](http://www.apple.com/ipad/from-the-app-store/apps-by-apple/garageband.html) is a good choice.